# displaying long mat-error value inside mat-form-field hides the message due to overflow: hidden generated by material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm new to "material" and trying to avoid issue of hiding error message like on the screenshot:

[image]

It's due to `overflow:hidden` style as highlighted on the picture:

[image]

If I turn it off or replace by `overflow:visible` I'll get the desired behavior:

[image]

The problem is I can't find a way to override the style as mat-form-subscript-wrapper is something "material" generates. If I put `overflow:visible` to its parent or child it does not work, it only works applied to mat-form-subscript-wrapper element.

I'd like to avoid solutions based on soon to be deprecated ng-deep

Comment: I added
`div.mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper {
 overflow: visible !important;
}` to common styles.scss and now it seems to work fine

Comment: You should add your comment as an answer; that's what worked for me. Not sure why component styling isn't getting picked up.